# CSS Grid - Stretch & wrap row based on adjacent siblings with a flat DOM

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

Trying to figure out how to get a grid layout with stretching rows based on number of adjacent siblings. Open to grid/flexbox/(other) solutions in SCSS or CSS.

[image: desired view]

The list is generated from some configs.
I have no idea how long, how many, or what order I may receiving the items.
There are some rules like, `item-type-a` is always a full row and `item-type-b` should stretch to fill the row with a maximum of 3 per row.

**Is this possible *with pure CSS*?**

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
    <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
    <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
    <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
    <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
    <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
    <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
    <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
    <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  </div>
```

To make the picture I used this CSS but need to a way to remove `item-type-c` & `item-type-d`

```html
<style>
  .container {
    background: white;
    border: dashed red 1px;
    padding: 24px;
    max-width: 1080px;
    display: grid;
    gap: 2rem 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  }

  .item {
    background: lightgray;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 100px;

    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
  }

  .item-type-a {
    grid-column: auto / span 12;
  }

  .item-type-b {
    grid-column: auto / span 6;
  }

  .item-type-c {
    grid-column: auto / span 4;
  }

  .item-type-d {
    grid-column: auto / span 12;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You can't do that with CSS-Grid or with flexbox I suspect. You're gonna need JS.

Comment: There is no `nth-of-row` option in either layout method.

Comment: This is about the closest I could get with flexbox, and pure CSS (there is some JavaScript to allow you to add new elements, and provide instruction for that functionality, but nothing that affects the CSS). It's not ideal though, if you add a fourth `.item-type-b` for example it takes a full line, rather than splitting into two lines of two: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rcbogjah/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  background: white;
  border: dashed red 1px;
  padding: 24px;
  max-width: 1080px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2rem 2rem;
}

.item {
  background: lightgray;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 2rem);
}

.item-type-a {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-b">Type B</div>
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
  <div class="item item-type-a">Type A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I must have been overly complicating things but this combo works for my case.